# is there any option in drupal to create a node for a particular user?

Tags: 7

I am going to create a medical lab examination system.In which i would have to display lab results to users individually.i will implement it by creating individual node for different different users, is there any option in drupal to create a node for a particular user ?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I see to do this is by following these steps:

1. Install [References](https://drupal.org/project/references) module.
2. Enable User reference module under admin > modules
3. Create a content type (say "lab result"), and add a field of type user reference.
4. Now, every time you create a "lab result" you could associate it with an user.
5. For listing the "lab result" of a particular user you could use the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module.